# VLC-Player in adobe Air App does not stop/quit

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Well i have an adobe air , downloaded from below link.. it is wonderful app..

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/air_screenrecording.html

and this works fine. It captures my screen , record audio but it just does not stop or quit as vlc-player.exe continues to run in the task manager.

i tried lots of vlc- commands but it just does not stop once it starts capturing screen video.

I need help on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quit using vlc for the same reason and started to write my recording application using .Net 4, but i am having less performance using c# now.

Edit:
VLC for windows does not support fake rc control so setting rc-fake-tty is useless. As the very last try, i wanna control is via socket. If you got it working this way, please make me informed.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old thread, but just in case someone wants to know...

You can't use rc-fake-tty because Windows doesn't support terminal. For Windows, tell VLC to run with only one instance, then send it the quit command as a separate NativeProcess call.

So, in the linked article, change the `stopRecording()` method to this:

```
public function stopRecording():void{
    var startupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
    startupInfo.executable = vlcFile;

    var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
    processArgs.push("-I");
    processArgs.push("rc"); //Remote control
    processArgs.push("--one-instance");
    processArgs.push("vlc://quit");
    startupInfo.arguments = processArgs;

    var killSwitch:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
    killSwitch.start(startupInfo);
}
```

And make sure to add this:

```
processArgs.push("--one-instance");
```

To your initial screen record startupInfo in `startRecording()` method.